# Allowing for Duplicates using options_for_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my app I am using options_for_select for a drop-down in a form. This Rails helper (I think) is removing duplicate values. The code is as follows:

```
<%= thing.select(:uuid, options_for_select(@user.things.collect{|t| [t.nick, t.uuid]})) %>
```

Few of the *things* have no :nick and therefore are an empty string. However, each of the things have a unique UUID. So one could have multiple things with no or the same :nick but different UUIDs.

The helper is only displaying 1 of the records with a nick as an empty and ignoring the others. This should not be the case (in my app) as the others have unique UUIDs.

Any idea how I can fix this?

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the method "select" on whatever the "thing" variable is assigned to.

Use:

```
<%= select_tag(:uuid, options_for_select(@user.things.collect{|t| [t.nick, t.uuid]})) %>
```

see [select_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag) for more information